# When setting up a new rails app with devise and activeadmin the schema.rb ends up empty

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise

I have now set up around 3-4 rails apps using Rails Composer:

1. I create the Rails app using rails composer using a MySQL database
2. I setup active admin

Then at some point during the setup running `bin/rake db:migrate` completely clears my `schema.rb` and the users table is removed.

I always have to restart my computer and run `bin/rake db:migrate` again and my `schema.rb` is then fixed.

I have no idea why this problem occurs but I think it's related to devise and active admin (which in turn uses devise as well).

The problem only occurs during the setup and I usually don't have that problem again.

The `schema.rb` when this happens:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

end
```

Why does this occur?

Answer (score 0):

try rebuild your database:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```